# Usage of Shared Preferences in android library projects

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Usage of Shared Preferences in android library projects is allowed?I am trying to work on rating bar but i am not sure whether i can use Shared preferences to write that.

Comment: yes i am doing that but just curious to know whether android library projects allows using shared preferences??

Comment: see here . if he can do things then you can also do what you want.https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Context`, supplied to you by the app that is using your library, you can use `SharedPreferences`.

However, you need to be a bit careful to ensure that you do not accidentally try using the *same* keys as the app might use. You might consider using a unique `SharedPreferences` file, rather than `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.